# Flickering page transitions in Jquery mobile app

Tags: html, cordova, jquery-mobile

How do i overcome the Flickering transition/ white-flash/ jumps during Mobile page transitions in a Web app? I use Jquerymobile and Phonegap's (.js) files. None of the solutions posted on  https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4024 or other sites worked for me. I do not use a separate jqueryTransition.js file. Any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only real way to prevent the "flickering" is to disable the jQuery Mobile page transitions altogether. In the `<head>` of your document, place this code:

```
// load jQuery
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

// load your custom jQuery Mobile Defaults
<script type="text/javascript" src="mobile/js/mobile-site-custom-jqm-defaults.js"></script>

// load jQuery Mobile
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

// load your scripts.js (your javascript & functions, etc.)
<script type="text/javascript" src="mobile/js/script.js"></script>
```

To disable transitions, inside of the `mobile-site-custom-jqm-defaults.js` file, place this code:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
  $.extend(  $.mobile , {
   defaultPageTransition: 'none'
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I just tried but it does not solve the problem!

Comment: Hi @Adam , you were close. Instead of 
 defaultPageTransition: 'none';   i used 

 $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
 $.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = 'none';

This solved the problem considerably, if not totally!

Answer (score 0):

I only came across flickering transitions while using LimeJS framework, they overcame that by setting the opacity of the object to 0 before transitioning. And from there the transition effect took over by increasing the opacity, but maybe your functionality doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, and solved it by disabling hardware acceleration.

I reported it here: http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/disable_hardwareacceleratdisable_hardwareacceleration_on_android_ion_on_android

To make it short, my workaround was declaring in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="false"/>
```

See also: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#hwaccel

HTH

Comment: Hi, thanks for the information! This is something unheard of.. Will definitely give it a shot and check the performance!

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesnt support for API lesser than 11 (Android 3.0)
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Comment: What are your minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion? Maybe this flag is defaulted to "true" because of the targetSdkVersion

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#hwaccel says: Whether or not hardware-accelerated rendering should be enabled for all activities and views in this application — "true" if it should be enabled, and "false" if not. The default value is "true" if you've set either minSdkVersion or targetSdkVersion to "14" or higher; otherwise, it's "false".

Comment: The important part i: The default value is "true" if you've set either minSdkVersion or targetSdkVersion to "14" or higher; otherwise, it's "false"