# Flash while page transition - Android 4.0.3

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

How can I remove white flash while page transition in Phonegap android 4.0.3? I am using jQuery Mobile 1.3.1, I have tried,

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
overflow: hidden;
```

But its not working.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

See if you have `data-position='fixed'` anywhere in your code. I used this line to make my footer stick to the bottom but it also produced this flash.

However since I don't use Phonegap in my application, you might want to try a Phonegap specific fix such as this one posted in a similar question:

[Flickering page transitions in Jquery mobile app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195433/flickering-page-transitions-in-jquery-mobile-app)

A more drastic fix would be to disable the page transitions altogether (which is probably not desireable because it is one of the primary reasons for using JQuery Mobile).